# Downloading multiple JSON arrays Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am making an android app that downloads Images and text from a web service, the issue am experiencing is that every time i transition to a new activity, the new activity fails to download data, when i go back to my default activity which works properly when the app is first launched too fails to download data as well, how Can I deal with this problem, any open source Libraries I can Implement? I have 10 activities all of which are downloading data, I am using AsyncTask.

Comment: you should use service

Comment: how should i implement it because each activity is downloading different data?

Comment: few minutes and I tell you how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make a new class called `MyService` for example which extends `Service`:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("","startcommand is called");








    return START_STICKY; //restart automatically if service destroyed   
}


/*your code write it here for downloading your images and text ,you should   
 use asyntask inside it*/
public void startDownloading(){


}

//this IBinder is used for communicating with your activity
private final IBinder binder=new MyBinder();



//this use for binding with activity
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}



/*this class used only by the activity to access the service through it 
,will work only this way*/
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public MyService getService(){
            return MyService.this;
        }



 }

 }//end class
```

And now in your each of your activity in your `oncreate` method write the following code

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

    //starting the service
    startService(intent);
    /*bind service to the actvitiy so that they can communicate between each    
     other*/
    bindService(intent, serviceconnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

You need a `ServiceConnection` which gets you a reference of `MyService` and tells you when the service is connected or disconnected:

```
 //to know when service is connected or disconnected to this activity
private ServiceConnection serviceconnection=new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MyService.MyBinder mybinder=(MyService.MyBinder)service;
        myservice=mybinder.getService();//a reference of MyService
        myservice.startDownloading();//your function for downloading image


    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.i("","disconnected to service");


    }
};
```

And don't forget to unbind from the service in the `onDestroy` method or `onPause` method:

```
 unbindService(serviceconnection); //unbind service from the activity
```

To communicate back with your activity when download is complete you can use interface or handlers.

Answer (score 1):

execute method of AsyncTask (in earlier versions I think after android 3) works sequentialy 
it means the next call for execute method waits until the current one finishes
if you want to change this behavior you must use method executeOnExecutor and ThreadPool
something like this

```
yourTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: how is normal asynctask different from AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR and how can i use it?

Comment: it is a normal AsyncTask but instead of calling execute ,call the method I have mentioned in answer.